# Airflow - Task Instance in EMR operator

Tags: python, emr, airflow

In Airflow, I'm facing the issue that I need to pass the `job_flow_id` to one of my emr-steps. I am capable of retrieving the `job_flow_id` from the operator but when I am going to create the steps to submit to the cluster, the `task_instance` value is not right.
I have the following code:

```
def issue_step(name, args):
    return [
        {
            "Name": name,
            "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
            "HadoopJarStep": {
                "Jar": "s3://....",
                "Args": args
            }
        }
    ]

dag = DAG('example',
          description='My dag',
          schedule_interval='0 8 * * 6',
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(days=2))

try:

    create_emr = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='create_job_flow',
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',        
        dag=dag
    )

    load_data_steps = issue_step('load', ['arg1', 'arg2'])

    load_data_steps[0]["HadoopJarStep"]["Args"].append('--cluster-id')
    load_data_steps[0]["HadoopJarStep"]["Args"].append(
        "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}") # the value here is not exchanged with the actual job_flow_id

    load_data = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='load_data',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",  # this is correctly exchanged with the job_flow_id - same for the others
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=load_data_steps,
        dag=dag
    )

    check_load_data = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='watch_load_data',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('load_data', key='return_value')[0] }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='remove_cluster',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    create_emr_recommendations >> load_data
    load_data >> check_load_data
    check_load_data >> cluster_remover

except AirflowException as ae:
    print ae.message
```

The problem is that, when I check the EMR, instead of seeing the `--cluster-id j-1234` in the `load_data` step, I see `--cluster-id "{{task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value')}}"`, which causes my step to fail.

How can I get the actual value inside my step function ?

Thanks and happy holidays

Comment: did you try appending the value without the quotes? load_data_steps[0]["HadoopJarStep"]["Args"].append(
        {{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }})

Comment: where do i get the ```task_instance``` object from ? I'm still learning how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that there is PR on airflow repository about [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2480). The issue is that there is no templating for steps in the `EmrAddStepsOperator`. To overcome this issue, I did the following:

- Created a custom operator that inherits from `EmrAddStepsOperator`
- Added this operator as Plugin
- Called the newly operator in my DAG file

Here the code for the custom operator and the plugin in file `custom_emr_add_step_operator.py` (see tree below)

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils import apply_defaults

from airflow.contrib.operators.emr_add_steps_operator import EmrAddStepsOperator


class CustomEmrAddStepsOperator(EmrAddStepsOperator):
    template_fields = ['job_flow_id', 'steps'] # override with steps to solve the issue above

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomEmrAddStepsOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        super(CustomEmrAddStepsOperator, self).execute(context=context)


# Defining the plugin class
class CustomPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "custom_plugin"
    operators = [CustomEmrAddStepsOperator]
```

In my DAG file I called the plugin in this way

```
from airflow.operators import CustomEmrAddStepsOperator
```

The structure of my project and plugins looks like this:

```
├── config
│   └── airflow.cfg
├── dags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_dag.py
├── plugins
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── operators
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── custom_emr_add_step_operator.py
└── requirements.txt
```

If you are using an IDE such as PyCharm, this will complain because it says that it cannot find the module. But when you run Airflow, this problem will not appear.
Remember also to make sure that in your `airflow.cfg` you are going to point to the right `plugins` folder so that Airflow is able to read your newly created plugin.